# Using the same JWT token for the web and public API

Tags: authentication, api, jwt

Lets say my web client gets a JWT token for authentication so it can make request to the API server. Now, I'd like to create a public API (which will basically be the same as the api for the web client with minor changes) so people can make requests outside the webapp. Is it okay to use the same JWT token used for the web client to access the public API? I mean (if you forget about refresh tokens), any user could get his JWT token from the browser and make requests outside of it. Therefore I thought I could just present the JWT inside the webapp so people can copy it easier.
But is the whole idea stupid or okay?